# How to use a FreeMarker template in a Magnolia App?

Tags: content-management-system, freemarker, magnolia

I'm using Magnolia 5.4 and have developed an app following the documentation:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS54/Apps

The app is being rendered correctly in the magnolia shell.
Opening the app shows a «Hello World» message as described in the documentation:
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS54/Programming+an+app#Programminganapp-MainSubApp

I've removed the unnecessary code and ended up with this:

```java
public class HelloWorldMainSubAppViewImpl implements HelloWorldMainSubAppView {

    private VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
    private Listener listener;

    public HelloWorldMainSubAppViewImpl() {
        layout.setMargin(true);
        layout.setSpacing(true);
        layout.addComponent(new Label("Hello World!"));
    }

    @Override
    public Component asVaadinComponent() {
        return layout;
    }
}
```

Instead of using the Label component I would like to use a FreeMarker template where I define a custom view.

Having read through the documentation I haven't figured out yet how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem, based on the previous work.

This is the «EmbeddedPageSubApp» approach as described under «[Custom App](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Choose+the+right+app+type)»

1. Create a regular page somewhere in your navigation.
2. Open the Configuration app, go to `/modules/<APP_NAME>/apps/<APP_NAME>/subApps/main` and add a url property to the mainSubApp with an absolute path to the previously created page.
3. Change value of the class property  `/modules/<APP_NAME>/apps/<APP_NAME>/subApps/main` to `info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.embedded.EmbeddedPageSubAppDescriptor`
4. Change the value of the `subAppClass` property to `info.magnolia.ui.framework.app.embedded.EmbeddedPageSubApp`
5. If you don't want that page to be visible [restrict](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Roles+and+access+control+lists) its access within 'superuser' group / role so that only administrators can use it.

This binds that with an iframe. You should choose a blank template since the navigation elements of the embedded page are visible within the app.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong here but to my knowledge Freemarker is only used to create templates and unfortunately limited to it. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Template+scripts

On the other hand, What you want to do is to develop your custom app and here is an example of how to do that.
https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS54/My+first+content+app

Also, if you are motivated to move to latest Magnolia version, you can define your custom app pretty easily using [Content Types](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS60/Content+Types).

Hope that helps,

Cheers,