# How to create a custom form processor in Magnolia?

Tags: content-management-system, magnolia

**Problem**

I've created a [custom app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56477989/how-to-use-a-freemarker-template-in-a-magnolia-app/56733220#56733220) in magnolia which renders a form.

⋅ The app renders some information from jcr

⋅ User makes changes to that form and submits

⋅ How to persist these changes?

According to the magnolia [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS54/Form+module#Formmodule-Creatingacustomformprocessor) a custom form processor is needed.

**What I've done:**

1. Created a custom form processor
   `/modules/form/templates/components/myFormProcessor`
   [image: node]
2. Java Class

```java
public class Bla extends AbstractFormProcessor {

    @Override
    protected void internalProcess(Node content, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws FormProcessorFailedException {
        final String stopHere = "•••";
    }
}
```

3. Set form action

```html
<form action="./persistMyChanges" method="POST">
   •••
</form>
```

Unfortunately the debugger wont stop at `stopHere`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no such thing as a magnolia community here is what I did:

The custom form processor didn't work out in my case. I just wanted to handle the request, but to do that the magnolia way you have to:

⋅ Add a form component to your template

⋅ Define your template in any of the three types ([page](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Page+definition)|[area](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Area+definition)|[component](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Component+definition)) where Template ⊆ Page ⊆ Area ⊆ Component

⋅ Then you have to use the directives which depends on your configuration in my case it would have been this: `[@cms.area name="main"]`

⋅ I started getting template errors like:

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> stkfn [in template "templating-kit/pages/section/contentArea.ftl" at line 7, column 38]
```

Wasn't able to solve this even with the help of magnolia enterprise support.

I solved this using a [filter](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Filters).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using form components from magnolia forms modul than you should  create a new extra form processor to handle your request(similar to email processors)

In case you have a form with fixed values you can handle the request via model class or custom rest endpoint